# Emacs automatically visit tag table

Tags: emacs, ctags

Is there a way to configure emacs so that whenever I open a file under a certain *path* it will automatically search (and in case load) a TAGS file in a part of the path? So for instance when opening

***/usr/src/foo/baz/bar.c***.It will load

***/usr/src/foo/TAGS*** file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you going through this [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags). There is a good example of doing the same with etags (*Auto refresh of the tags file*) (which I won't post here), but hopefully it's no so hard to make it work for ctags.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this package http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EtagsTable It's available on MELPA and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.binchen.org/posts/how-to-use-ctags-in-emacs-effectively-3.html

The point is in this case, a little bit elisp code is more versatile, I've been using this solution for two years.